# Send Email Extracting Variable from CSV According to Date

Tags: powershell, csv

I'd like to automate an email via a scheduled task every Friday to tell the various sites to change the tapes for the weekend backups.

The rotation and tape numbers are in a csv file, along with the dates.

So I thought I could get the date and email the data from that date to the relevant departments.

What I have so far is below. I can read from the csv, but get everything output rather than just the information on that date. I've set `adddays -1` and thought that would capture any date up to yesterday?

```
$Data =import-csv "C:\New folder\csv-1.csv" | select "Item-Date", "Tape_1", "Tape_3", "Tape_2", "Rotation"
$CheckDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
    Where-Object {
        ($_."Item-Date" -as [DateTime]) -lt $CheckDate
    }
    $PSEmailServer = "SomeSMTPserver.com"
Send-MailMessage -From "User3@email.co.uk" -To "User2@email.co.uk" -cc "User@email.co.uk" -Subject "Tape Changes2" -Body "Hi User, Could you please change the tapes, inserting the tapes "$_.Tape_1", "$_.Tape_2", "$_.Tape_3", for rotation week "$_.Rotation". Thanks"
```

Comment: Hi, just had a thought, there are tape changes, such as adding and removing every other day, could I do an if statement, such as if todays date in csv then do the above?

Answer (score 1):

Your `where-object` isn't doing anything at the moment as it's not receiving any input from the pipeline or returning it's results to any variable.

It's hard to be certain without knowing your CSV data, but you probably want to do something like this (includes a `foreach-object` loop in case there are multiple results returned from the `where-object`):

```
$PSEmailServer = "SomeSMTPserver.com"

$Data =import-csv "C:\New folder\csv-1.csv" | select "Item-Date", "Tape_1", "Tape_3", "Tape_2", "Rotation"

$CheckDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
$TapeData = $Data | Where-Object { ($_."Item-Date" -as [DateTime]) -lt $CheckDate }

$TapeData | ForEach-Object {    
    Send-MailMessage -From "User3@email.co.uk" -To "User2@email.co.uk" -cc "User@email.co.uk" -Subject "Tape Changes2" -Body "Hi User, Could you please change the tapes, inserting the tapes $($_.Tape_1), $($_.Tape_2), $($_.Tape_3), for rotation week $($_.Rotation). Thanks"
}
```

Note as shown above you also need to wrap your strings in subexpressions `$()` as you are accessing a .property of them.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I'm getting the error below about positional parameter?

Comment: Send-MailMessage <<<<  -From "user@email.co.uk"  + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Send-MailMessage], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage

Comment: I corrected my answer a couple of times, as your input for `-body` had issues. Are you using subexpressions like this? : `Send-MailMessage -From "User3@email.co.uk" -To "User2@email.co.uk" -cc "User@email.co.uk" -Subject "Tape Changes2" -Body "Hi User, Could you please change the tapes, inserting the tapes $($_.Tape_1), $($_.Tape_2), $($_.Tape_3), for rotation week $($_.Rotation). Thanks"`

Comment: Hi, no I wasn't using subexpressions, I was only doing ($_.Tape_1), ($_.Tape_2), etc

Comment: You will need to make those $($_.Tape_1) etc. in order to access the property within a string. See here for a detailed explanation: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_stranger/2013/09/25/powershell-sub-expressions/

Comment: It is also possible to use string format. `-Body ("Hi User, Could you please change the tapes, inserting the tapes {0}, {1}, {2}, for rotation week {3}. Thanks" -f $_.Tape_1, $_.Tape_2, $_.Tape_3, $_.Rotation)`

Comment: Hi Thanks all for your comments, fascinating insight. This almost works perfectly, just one minor point, its giving me every output except todays, and I need todays and ignore the rest? I was thinking if I got that information and then compared it todays date and then only sent out todays date information.. does that make sense?? :)

Comment: Probably just need to change the `-lt` to `-gt` e.g: `($_."Item-Date" -as [DateTime]) -gt $CheckDate`

Comment: @ma Excellent.. that's brilliant.. thanks so much :)               Not to harp on about a point, but just wondered about the IF statement,

Comment: @MarkWragg Thanks Mark ..again :)

Comment: No problem, please accept/upvote the answer if it helped you.